# Python Twisted Scrapy AttributeError: 'DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory' object has no attribute 'privateKey'

Tags: python, scrapy, openssl, ssl-certificate, twisted

In this code, I am trying to use a certificate .key and .pem file for a private page which I am authorized to use.

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet import ssl

class BrowserLikeContextFactory(ScrapyClientContextFactory):


        def creatorForNetloc(self, hostname, port):


            certificate = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory('path\\sample.key','path\\sample.pem')

            return optionsForClientTLS(hostname.decode("ascii"),
                trustRoot=platformTrust(),
                clientCertificate=certificate,
                extraCertificateOptions={
                'method': self._ssl_method,
                    })
```

The two files exist in the path specified. I tried a fetch command in Scrapy and this was the first result.

[image]

However, after putting in the PEM pass phrase, this error was encountered? How do I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> certificate = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory('path\sample.key','path\sample.pem')

This isn't a certificate.  Later, something tries to use it as if it were and gets an attribute error because it doesn't have the `privateKey` attribute like a certificate would/should.

Try something like

```
with open("path/sample.key") as k:
    with open("path/sample.pem") as p:
        certificate = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(k.read() + p.read())
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer to your question, but it's too long for a comment. I find it easier NOT dealing with one-off certificates like self signed certificates or certificates for local/private servers. I've had success with something like this (taken from a `treq` project but should work for `scrapy` too, with some tweaking):

```py
import re

from twisted.internet import ssl
from twisted.web.iweb import IPolicyForHTTPS
from twisted.web.client import BrowserLikePolicyForHTTPS, Agent
from zope.interface import implementer

@implementer(IPolicyForHTTPS)
class RegexContextFactory:

    defaultPolicy = BrowserLikePolicyForHTTPS()

    def __init__(self, re_domains):
        self.re_domains = re.compile(re_domains)

    def creatorForNetloc(self, hostname, port):
        if self.re_domains.match(hostname) != None:
            return ssl.CertificateOptions(verify=False)
        return self.defaultPolicy.creatorForNetloc(hostname, port)

# Replace regex with one that will match your private domains
regex_factory = RegexContextFactory(b"^(dev|test|stage)-api\.private.net")
```

The `RegexContextFactory` accepts a regex (make sure it's `bytes` type) and ignores security measures for all TLS URLs that match the regex. All other URLs behave in the default manner.